# ERROR ReferenceError: cv is not defined in Angular electron app

Tags: javascript, angular, opencv, electron

I try to implement a face detection app using **OpenCv.js** in Angular electron app,
and I want to use [ng-open-cv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-open-cv) module from the npm modules.
but when I inject the NgOpenCVService to the constructor of any component I got the error message

ERROR ReferenceError: cv is not defined
[image]

so I tried to create a new Angular 8 project without an electron framework and it worked fine.

Now, I want to make it works in Angular electron app.

so, after a lot of testing, I found the source of the issue.

The guide of ng-open-cv ask you to create a typings.d.ts file in the src directory and add

```
declare var cv: any;
```

inside this file.

however, for some reason, the **angular-electron** looks like it doesn't see the **cv** attribute, though, in pure **Angular** it works well.

if you have any idea to solve this issue, share it with me and I appreciate it.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, and fixed it by declaring the cv var in the script where i was trying to use it:

```
import { forkJoin, Observable, empty, fromEvent, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
declare var cv: any; // <--- Here!

@Component({
```

I have made a repo based on open-cv sample of devakone, that was on Angular 6, and updated to a working version in Angular 12:

https://github.com/Of3lia/ng12-open-cv

I hope it was helpfull